# How do I replace Values/dtype: int64 in a pandas specific column of a dataframe to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using below code:

```
student_data_df.loc[(student_data_df["school_name"] == "Thomas High School") & (student_data_df["grade"] == "9th")]=np.nan
```

Output:

I am getting the complete row as NaN, Need only "reading_score" as Nan

[image]

Comment: `student_data_df.loc[(student_data_df["school_name"] == "Thomas High School") & (student_data_df["grade"] == "9th"), 'reading_score']=np.nan ` you are currently assign nan to the whole row so you need to add the column name to `loc` - i.e., `df.loc[row_indexer, column_indexer]`

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`). [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: ... `row_indexer = (student_data_df["school_name"] == "Thomas High School") & (student_data_df["grade"] == "9th"); col_indexer = "reading_score"; 
 student_data_df.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer]=np.nan`, [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: Thanks very much Chris, It works!!